# Extract residuals from lme4 in loop

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I want to extract the residuals from a linear mixed model loop.

```
results <- matrix(NA, nrow(meth),4,   dimnames=list(rownames(meth),  c("nobs", "coef", "coef.se", "Pval")))
```

The loop creates a matrix with the results for variable X but now I want to extract the residuals from that loop which would create the same matrix as meth (same dimentions) but then with the residuals. I tried:

```
#make matrix
res<- matrix(NA, nrow(meth),ncol(meth), dimnames=list(rownames(meth), colnames(meth)) )
#run loop
for (i in 1:(nrow(meth))) {
  y <- (meth[i,])
  model <- try(lmer(as.formula(f), data=(sample_trans))
               , silent=TRUE)
  if (!inherits(model, "try-error")) {
      res[i,] <- resid(model)
  }
}
```

but I get the error:

> ```
> Error in res[i, ] <- resid(model) : 
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> ```

There are NA in the data but that should not affect it because I used try. Is there something wrong with the loop itself?

Comment: the code does not make sense to me. you generate `y` but never use?

Comment: If you have NA values the default na.omit removes them before the fitting. Obviously, residuals are then not the same length in your loop.

Comment: @amatsuo_net, I use it in the as.formula(f) but it is not shown here.

Comment: @Roland, oke yes that makes sense but how do I alter the loop that it will putt NA when there are NA's or when it does use the y in the formula for some reason?

Comment: Try if lme4 supports na.exclude.